# Copy files from Github Enterprise Repo to a Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, github, azure-devops, copy

I have a need to copy files from Github enterprise repo (to be more specific, whatever exists under master branch) to a directory in Linux VM from an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Here, I have listed few options that I found from documentation and few from Stack Overflow discussions, and why I do not like to opt these options:

1. Azure File Copy task requires intermediate storage account but I would not like to configure the same.
2. This discussion recommends SSH task. SSH task requires a private key to be configured on the target VM in addition to the VM user name and password. But, I would not like to configure the same.
   [Can I push code from Azure devops to Azure VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769952/can-i-push-code-from-azure-devops-to-azure-vm)
3. This discussion recommends Windows File Copy task but I do not see something similar for LINUX.
   [Obtain the artifact directory path as a relative path for the Release process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924643/obtain-the-artifact-directory-path-as-a-relative-path-for-the-release-process)
4. This discussion is closer to my need but I would not like to "deploy" but just "copy"
   [Deploy python script to virtual machine from GitHub via Azure Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817269/deploy-python-script-to-virtual-machine-from-github-via-azure-pipeline)

Appreciate a mindshare on this need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use ssh key and azure storage account, I suggest that you can consider using the [Self-hosted Linux Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops).

Then you can directly copy the files to linux server via using the Self-hosted agent in Azure Pipeline.